# [Symfony 5]Confirmation message after logout

Tags: symfony, security, logout

On Symfony 5, using the built-in login system, it seems impossible to add a confirmation message after logout. I have followed strictly the steps described on [the official website](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#logging-out). Unfortunately, the method logout inside the SecurityController is useless. I'm redirected directly on the login page.

Here you will have my security.yaml file :

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: auto


# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: lazy
        provider: app_user_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: login

        remember_me:
            secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     home
            always_remember_me: true

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: ^/logout$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, ROLE_ADMIN] }
    - { path: ^/profile, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, ROLE_USER] }
```

And the Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        if ($this->getUser()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => null, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        throw new \Exception('Don\'t forget to activate logout in security.yaml');
    }
}

?>
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For anyone who's wondering how exactly they can implement the external redirect with the new logout customization:

As stated in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-simpler-logout-customization), create a new CustomLogoutListener class and add it to your services.yml configuration.

The CustomLogoutListener class should implement the *onSymfonyComponentSecurityHttpEventLogoutEvent* method, which will receive the *LogoutEvent* as a parameter, that will allow you to set the response:

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use JetBrains\PhpStorm\NoReturn;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\LogoutEvent;

class CustomLogoutListener
{
    /**
     * @param LogoutEvent $logoutEvent
     * @return void
     */
    #[NoReturn]
    public function onSymfonyComponentSecurityHttpEventLogoutEvent(LogoutEvent $logoutEvent): void
    {
        $logoutEvent->setResponse(new RedirectResponse('https://where-you-want-to-redirect.com', Response::HTTP_MOVED_PERMANENTLY));
    }
}
```

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    # ...
    App\EventListener\CustomLogoutListener:
        tags:
            - name: 'kernel.event_listener'
              event: 'Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\LogoutEvent'
              dispatcher: security.event_dispatcher.main
```

Comment: To avoid this long method name `onSymfonyComponentSecurityHttpEventLogoutEvent`: in your `services.yaml` set the `method: onLogoutEvent`-Tag so you can name your method `onLogoutEvent`.

Answer (score 3):

logout method in SecurityController won’t actually get hit because Symfony will intercept the request.
if you need to do something after logout you can use logout success handler

```php
namespace App\Logout;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface;

class MyLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        // you can do anything here
        return new Response('logout successfully'); // or render a twig template here, it's up to you
    }
}
```

and you can register your logout success handler to security.yaml

```yaml
firewalls:
    main:
        anonymous: lazy
        provider: app_user_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: logout
            success_handler: App\Logout\MyLogoutSuccessHandler # assume you have enable autoconfigure for servicess or you need to register the handler
```

Answer (score 2):

As of version 5.1 LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface is deprecated, it is recommended to use **LogoutEvent**.

> Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface is deprecated

But there are no examples or information about **LogoutEvent** in the official documentation

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Indra Gunawan, this solution works. My goal was to redirect to the login page with a message like "You've been successfully logged out".

In that case, the LogoutSuccessHandler must be adapted to route to the login page :

```
namespace App\Logout;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class MyLogoutSuccessHandler extends AbstractController implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{

    private $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('login', ['logout' => 'success']));
    }
}
```

The route login need to be defined in routes.yaml :

```
login:
    path: /login
    controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::login

logout:
    path: /logout
    methods: GET
```

In that case, when logout, you will be redirected on an url like : /login?logout=success

Lastely, you can catch logout parameter in twig template like :

```
    {%- if app.request('logout') -%}
        <div class="alert alert-success">{% trans %}Logout successful{% endtrans %}</div>
    {%- endif -%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the doc for the LogoutEvent :

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-simpler-logout-customization

You must create an event and implement the onSymfonyComponentSecurityHttpEventLogoutEvent's method.
Its work for me

Comment: To avoid this long method name `onSymfonyComponentSecurityHttpEventLogoutEvent`: in your `services.yaml` set the `method: onLogoutEvent`-Tag so you can name your method `onLogoutEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Symfony 6 and above you can use as bellow

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\LogoutEvent;

class LogoutListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public function onLogout(LogoutEvent $logoutEvent): void
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            LogoutEvent::class => 'onLogout',
        ];
    }
}
```